# Reloading a table's data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, reload

I have 5 view controllers, which are in a navigation controller hierarchy. When I reach my last view controller, there's a button that lets me go back to the "Home" view controller (named CardWalletViewController) which is a table view controller. Here's the method I have in my last VC (`PointsResultsVC`)

```
- (IBAction)homePressed:(id)sender {
    NSArray *VCs = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[VCs objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

CardWalletVC's cells is being filled up by values coming from the saved instances of a Card in NSUserDefaults and it works fine.

Now, what I want is to update the value in my `CardWalletViewController`, which is the points of a card coming from my `PointsResultsVC`. Note that this points is saved in `NSUserDefault`s.

Upon the process of trying to update of the value shown in my CardWalletVC, I placed `[self.tableView reloadData];` inside `-viewDidLoad`, `-viewWillAppear`, and -`viewDidAppear` of the said class. I tried placing it one by one in each of this methods, yet it doesn't seem to work.

Advice Please.

**EDIT: problem solved**

This one served as my guide [Save data from one tab and reloadData in another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342458/save-data-from-one-tab-and-reloaddata-in-another-tab).

And as I have discovered, `-viewDidLoad` of a certain class will only be called once, all throughout runtime of app. Whereas `-viewWillAppear`, it will be called every time the view appears.

So, I just moved the way I am loading the values saved in NSUserDefaults from  `-viewDidLoad` to `-viewWillAppear`. Also, inside `-viewWillAppear` I placed the `[self.tableView reloadData]`. Then there, problem solved.

Comment: have u tried placing an NSLog inside each viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear?? and then, see if the NSLog is fired or not, this way you could determine wether it's the method that's not fired, OR your table reload the same / wrong data

Comment: maybe a delaying of the selector's execution would work `[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(mySelector:) withObject:NULL afterDelay:2.0];`

Comment: remark : note that viewDidLoad might be called multiple times (!), it's a mistake many people make - if your app gets a low memory warning, your views might get unloaded by iOS, whether you like it or not. Which will make viewDidLoad be called again next time your app needs to display  that window. Apart from that, in general you will  load your data in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, not in ViewDidLoad (unless it's truly static, but still it's bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things that *could* be going wrong so you'll need to provide more info to narrow it down.

First of all, viewDidLoad will not be called so you can remove it from here. Both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear will be called, so you only need it one of these 2 methods.

Next, you need to determine what the actual issue is.

1 - is self.tableView a proper reference to the table? Are you properly maintaining the reference?

2 -  is the table actually reloading but using the old data, or is it not reloading at all? You can log the willDisplayCell method to see what is going on when the view appears.

With that info, the root cause can be narrowed down to a solvable problem.